# Problem about the Definition of Large Deviation Principle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

As in many classic textbooks, the definitions of Large Deviation Principle is as follows:

**$\{\mu_n\}$ has LDP with speed $a_n$ and rate $I(x)$ if the following holds for any measurable $A$:
$$\limsup\frac{1}{a_n}\log\mu_n(A)\leq -\inf_{x\in\bar{A}}I(x),$$
$$\liminf\frac{1}{a_n}\log\mu_n(A)\geq -\inf_{x\in A^{o}}I(x).$$**

I was wondering why we need the closure and interior as upper and lower bounds here(resp.), instead of use the infimum on $A$ directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extra distinction is to be careful about vanishing mass.

$\textbf{(liminf)}$ Let $\mu_n$ all be be without atoms, $y$ such that $I(y) < \infty$ and $A=\{y\}$ a singleton. Then for all $n$, $\mu_n(\{y \}) = 0$, so (since $\{y \}^{\mathrm{o}} = \emptyset$)

$$ \liminf \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} \log \mu_n(\{y\}) = - \infty = - \inf \limits_{x \in \{y \}^{\mathrm{o}}} I(x) < - \inf \limits_{x \in \{y \}} I(x) = -I(y).$$

$\textbf{(limsup)}$ Also here, we do not want positive mass to 'leak out into the boundary of an open set' (a formulation kindly borrowed from [here](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/weak-convergence-and-the-portmanteau-lemma/)). For example, let $X_k \sim \text{Uniform}(\{-1,1\})$ i.i.d. (or any nontrivial distribution with bounded support and finite moment generating function).

Then, $S_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $\tilde{S}_n := (1 + \frac{1}{n}) S_n$ satisfy the Large Deviation Principle (by Cramér's Theorem and exponential equivalence), but clearly

$$\mathbb{P}[\tilde{S}_n < -1] = \mathbb{P}[X_1=\dots=X_n=-1] = \frac{1}{2^n},$$
so we have for $\mu_n := \text{Law}_{\mathbb{P}}(\tilde{S}_n)$ and the open set $A=(- \infty, -1)$,

$$\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mu_n((- \infty, -1)) = -\log{2} = -\inf \limits_{x \in \overline{(\infty, -1)}} I(x) > -\inf \limits_{x \in (\infty, -1)} I(x) = - \infty,$$
since $I$ is only finite in $[-1,1]$.